# Spring - Registering new user in existing UserDetailsService bean within autoconfiguration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

So, I have the following scenario: I need to configure Spring Security for the Actuator endpoints. All this should be in an external library, as part of an autoconfiguration class dependent on a certain property. Access to some of those endpoints should only be allowed for a special role (I've configured an `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` just for the sake of it).

The applications using this external library can have their own security configurations. If the `UserDetailsService` bean does not exist in the app context the autoconfigured one is created. The problem is the following - if I declare an `UserDetailsService` in the app configuration, the autoconfiguration class updates it with the actuator admin user (and I can see that both users exist): the security configuration is all messed up though (I am getting 401 when using the correct credentials).

Does anyone know how to manage this?

The autoconfiguration class (in external library - Kotlin):

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Props::class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = Props.PROPERTY_PREFIX, name = ["securityEnabled"])
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = SERVLET)
open class ActuatorSecurityAutoConfiguration(private val props: Props) {

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(PasswordEncoder::class)
public open fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
    return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(UserDetailsService::class)
public open fun actuatorUserDetailsManager(passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
                                           userDetailsManager: UserDetailsManager): UserDetailsManager {
    userDetailsManager.createUser(
            User.withUsername(props.username)
                    .password(props.password)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder::encode)
                    .roles(ACTUATOR_USER_ROLE)
                    .build())
    
    return userDetailsManager
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(UserDetailsService::class)
public open fun defaultActuatorUserDetailsManager(passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder): UserDetailsManager {
    return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(listOf(
            User.withUsername(props.username)
                    .password(props.password)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder::encode)
                    .roles(ACTUATOR_USER_ROLE)
                    .build()
    ))
}

@Bean
@Throws(Exception::class)
@Order(100) //the order is not respected as this is loaded after the main config class
public open fun actuatorSecurityFilterChain(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    httpSecurity
            .antMatcher("/actuator/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests {
                it.antMatchers("/actuator/info", "/actuator/health").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().hasRole(ACTUATOR_USER_ROLE)
            }
            .headers().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic()

    return httpSecurity.build()
}
```

The configuration class in the application using the external library:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Value("${credentials.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${credentials.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${credentials.role}")
private String role;

private final AuthClient authClient;

public DashboardSecurityConfiguration(AuthClient authClient) {
    this.authClient = authClient;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.antMatcher("/secure_endpoint/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole(role)
            )
            .authenticationProvider(new SsoAuthenticationProvider(authClient))
            .addFilterBefore(new SsoTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .httpBasic();

    return httpSecurity.build();
}

@Bean
@Order
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().permitAll())
            .headers().disable()
            .csrf().disable();

    return httpSecurity.build();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsManager() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(List.of(
            createUser(username, password, role)
    ));
}

private UserDetails createUser(String username, String password, String... roles) {
    return User.builder()
            .username(username)
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode(password))
            .roles(roles)
            .build();
}
```

application.properties:

```
prefix.securityEnabled=true
```

I can access `/actuator` endpoints without issues (even the secured paths) if I comment out the `UserDetailsService` in the Java application, but I can no longer access them (including `/secure_endpoint`) once I include it back in.

Any thoughts? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are the UserDetailService users being created? Perhaps the default user with autogenerated password (printed in console as INFO level log) is the only user that exists in the system.

Output for me looks like below:

```
2023-03-23T08:26:56.826+08:00  INFO 36604 --- [           main] ctiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :

Using generated security password: 89113256-0a54-4fec-84bb-872d48506f4e
```